# Application insights - ok to leave running in production?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an existing mvc web app running on azure websites.

I have set application insights running on it whilst it is live.

Is this recommended practise? Will this have any impact on my site whilst it is running? is it okay to leave this running as it provides very useful data...

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely, Application Insights is intended to be able to run in production alongside your applications.

One of its purposes is to help you track the health of your application and assist you when something goes wrong.

While it is optimized to operate as silently as possible, impacting your performance inevitable. Unless you're tracing a lot of custom data or very performance-dependent - you should be fine.